# Class 'App\NewsLetterManager' not found - Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, mailchimp, newsletter

I get this error (when I try to subscribe to a monthly newsletter)

```
Class 'App\NewsLetterManager' not found
```

When I have this website running locally (on vagrant) it all works fine, but when I transfer my project to the online server I get the error above.

In my Controller I DO use the NewsLetterManager.. So no idea what is going on.

Controller (snippet)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\NewsLetterManager;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    ..

    public function addToMailingList(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:195'
        ]);
        $newsLetterManager = new NewsLetterManager($mailchimp = app('Mailchimp'));
        $newsLetterManager->addEmailToList($request->email);

        return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'mailing');
    }

    ..

}
```

Blade

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('mailing.add') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input class="bordered-input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Subscribe here" />
</form>
```

Routes

```
    Route::post('/mailing/add', ['as' => 'mailing.add', 'uses' => 'Controller@addToMailingList']);
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to upload your up-to-date vendor folder into the server or update your composer in the server.

Comment: I tried `composer dump-autoload` and `composer update` and `composer install`. Also manually dragging my vendor folder to the FTP did not work.